# Docker [ nginx | php | mysql ] response time is very long

Tags: php, macos, docker, nginx

We use exactly same Docker version and macOS on different mac devices . ( MiniMac & MacBook Pro) also use same docker-compose.yml on both of them, But response time is very different

For example in the attached image total response time is:

- MacBook : 2655ms
- Mini mac: 80ms

Can anyone help me with this??

[Screenshot -> MacBook Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hjGY.jpg)

[Screenshot -> Mini Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCFnJ.jpg)

Comment: Please add more log to make this question more clear, for example are you using 3 docker images? or just one image. can you provide logs? can you test static file over nginx? is it same?

Comment: This is my  [docker-composer.yml](https://github.com/saderi/lamp-docker)

Comment: did you test it with static file? to see is it because of nginx or fpm-lpm?